# How to access JWT claims from API handler functions in go-swagger?

Tags: jwt, swagger, openapi, go-swagger

I'm using go-swagger with `BearerAuth` using JWT tokens. Along with the actual token I'm receiving  claims which include such data as username.

How can I access claims in `api.ItemsCreateItemHandler` function below?

```
package restapi

func configureAPI(api *operations.MyAPI) http.Handler {
    api.BearerAuth = func(token string) (interface{}, error) {
        jwtToken := strings.Replace(token, "Bearer ", "", -1)
        // skipped token verification

        claims, _ := parsedToken.Claims.(jwt.MapClaims)
  }

  api.ItemsCreateItemHandler = items.CreateItemHandlerFunc(func(params items.CreateItemParams, principal interface{}) middleware.Responder {
    // FIXME: Here I need to be able to access JWT claims
    if err := createItem(params.Body, claims); err != nil {
            return nil // handle error
        }
        return items.NewCreateItemCreated()
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First your `BearerAuth` implementation is meant to return the security principal (which can be your claims in this case), this value will subsequently be passed to your handler in the `principal` argument.

So the way to do this is:

```golang
package restapi

import (
    jwt "github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go"
    // ...
)

func configureAPI(api *operations.MyAPI) http.Handler {
    api.BearerAuth = func(token string) (interface{}, error) {
        jwtToken := strings.Replace(token, "Bearer ", "", -1)
        // skipped token verification
        claims, _ := parsedToken.Claims.(jwt.MapClaims)
        return claims, nil
    }

    api.ItemsCreateItemHandler = items.CreateItemHandlerFunc(func(params items.CreateItemParams, principal interface{}) middleware.Responder {
        claims, ok := principal.(jwt.MapClaims)
        if !ok {
            // handle error
        }
        if err := createItem(params.Body, claims); err != nil {
            return nil // handle error
        }
        return items.NewCreateItemCreated()
    })
}
```

You can make this less cumbersome by using the `--principal jwt.MapClaims` option to `swagger generate` so that it uses this type for the claims instead of `interface{}`.

Answer (score -1):

A JWT is made up of 3 parts, split by punctuation - the token itself is base64 encoded.

For example, heres a token from https://jwt.io/

> eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c

You'll want to split and decode, you're after the second part which contains the payload which is just plain JSON.

So in psuedo code it'll look something like;

```
json = Base64Decode(split(".", yourData)[1])
```

You'll see more concrete example at https://jwt.io/

Answer (score -1):

I have a class that store token and contains parse method:

```
import io.jsonwebtoken.*;

 @AllArgsConstructor
public class RawAccessJwtToken implements JwtToken {

    private String token;

    @Override
    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public Jws<Claims> parseClaims(String signingKey) {
        try {
            return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(signingKey).parseClaimsJws(this.token);
        } catch (UnsupportedJwtException | MalformedJwtException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw  new BadCredentialsException("Invalid JWT token: " + e);
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException expiredException){
            throw new JwtExpiredTokenException(this, "JWT Token expired", expiredException);
        }
    }
}
```

With that class I can extract my users role:

```
 Jws<Claims> claimsJws = token.parseClaims(signingKey);

        List<String> scopes = claimsJws.getBody().get("scopes",
                 List.class);
```